# yield and while loop confusion due to unexpected outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys so I was wondering why when making the *make_song()* function it actually worked, I thought the version I'm going to show below would not work the way it did:

```
def make_song(count = 99, beverage = "soda"):
    while count > 0:
            if count > 1:
                yield "{} bottles of {} on the wall.".format(count, beverage)
                count -=1
            elif count == 1:
                yield "Only {} bottle of {} left!".format(count, beverage)
                count -= 1
                yield "No more {}!".format(beverage)

hey = make_song(5, "coke")
print(next(hey))
print(next(hey))
print(next(hey))
print(next(hey))
print(next(hey))
print(next(hey))
```

my conclusion was that when *count == 1* it would print:

> Only 1 bottle of coke left!
>
> No more coke!

because they were both under the same *if* statement. To my surprise, it worked the way I wanted it to work, by printing only "Only 1 bottle of coke left!" when the count == 1, and then when i used next() again it would print "No more coke!", I didn't expect this one to work,

why did it not print both yields when count == 1 even though they were under the same if statement?

Comment: `they were under the same if statement` has no meaning. Two yields, two results.

Comment: `yield` stops the execution of the function, like return, just next time you call this function it continues from the point where it  stopped. [what does the yield keyword do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the code that determines when the *generator* *gives* you something is `yield` and not `if`.
The `if` only determines which lines gets executed depending on a condition.

In practice a *generator* is a generalization of a function.
A function returns a value once, while a generator returns as many times as a `yield` statement is reached.
After each `yield` the execution is suspended, and upon the next call to `next()` the execution is resumed and continues until the next `yield` is found.

An alternative to the `next()` call is to use the iterator directly in a `for` loop, which will exhaust all possible `yield` endpoints.

For example:

```
for s in make_song(5, "coke"):
    print(s)
```

will give you:

```
5 bottles of coke on the wall.
4 bottles of coke on the wall.
3 bottles of coke on the wall.
2 bottles of coke on the wall.
Only 1 bottle of coke left!
No more coke!
```

Answer (score 1):

The way is

- each `yield` gives a value to return
- each call to `next` get the next value given by a `yield`

So as the `1 left` and `no more` are given by a different `yield` you 2 `next` to get them

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it return "Only 1 bottle of coke left!" in the second to last, and "No more coke!" on  the last next is that when you invoke next() in a method that yields the code on the method will  run until there there is a yield.

Let's say that you are in the count == 2:

```
 while count > 0:
     if count > 1:
         yield "{} bottles of {} on the wall.".format(count, beverage)
```

code checks that `count > 0` and continues to the next statement `count > 1` since `count == 2` it enters the if statement. The next line is the yield statement, which means it will return the string (and the line `count -= 1` will not be executed until the next `next()`).

When `next` is invoked again the code will continue decreasing the counter to 1, and it leaves the if statement and goes back to the while statement. The while statement still holds `True`, the `count > 1` now is `False`, therefore it goes to the `elif` statement which is `True`. The first statement is the `yield` that return `yield "Only 1 bottle of coke left!`. The following `next()` decrease the count and yields `No more coke!`